# Knockout sort with <select>

Tags: knockout.js

I currently have a sort implementation using Knockout where each column is a  that the user can click on to sort an ObservableArray by that column. I'd like to convert it into a , and I'm close- choosing one of the columns in the Sort  I created does call the sort function, but does not pass the property to sort by to that sort function like the original implementation does. I've tried calling like "sort(sortType)" to explicitly pass in the property I'd like to sort by, but that doesn't work/ such a thing isn't needed for the original implementation.

Original Sort Code:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: headers" class="headers">
  <span data-bind="click: $parent.sort, text: title"></span>
</div>
```

Select Sort Code:

```
<select data-bind="event: { change: sort}, options: headers, optionsText: 'title', optionsValue: 'sortType'">    </select>
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jspinella/d9z3k7tw/14/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use the `value` binding instead of the `change` event:

```
<select data-bind="value: sortMode, 
                   options: headers, 
                   optionsText: 'title'"></select>
```

Then, in your viewmodel, you can subscribe to `sortMode`:

```
var self = this;
this.sortMode = ko.observable("title");              
this.sort = function() {
  var sortProperty = self.sortMode();

  // Logic to sort by `sortProperty` goes here:
  // ...
};

this.sortMode.subscribe(this.sort);
```

---

### For your specific code/case

Check out my suggestion here: https://jsfiddle.net/u8tLLrLb/

Looking at the code, I'd propose to make `self.activeSort` an observable, introduce a `pureComputed` property named `sortMethod`, and a `pureComputed` array named `sortedMovies`:

```
self.activeSort = ko.observable(self.headers[0]);
self.sortMethod = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  var sortType = self.activeSort().sortType;
  switch (sortType) { /* return a function(a,b) { } */ }
});

self.sortedMovies = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  return self.movies().sort(self.sortMethod());
});
```

Then, your data-bind for the `<select>` will be:

```
<select data-bind="value: activeSort, 
               options: headers, 
               optionsText: 'title'"></select>
```

Changing this will update the `sortMethod`, which will update the `sortedMovies`.